# Подмена библиотечного класса своим

Tags: юнит-тесты, test-automation, тестирование, c++

Для тестирования своих классов хочу заменить некоторые классы из сторонних библиотек.
Кто подскажет как это правильней сделать?

Comment: >Кто подскажет как это правильней сделать?

правильней этого не делать

Comment: А интерфейс тот же? Если да, `#define` вам в помощь.

---
А вообще-то, правильно использовать dependency injection.

Comment: для юнит тестов подмена - это штатное дело. И называется mock. Ищите готовые или пишите сами. Так как это юнит тесты, то ничего не нужно подменять - хедер подключаете тот же, но вот lib каталог - другой.

Comment: @KoVadim: в «штатное дело» подмена lib превращается, если части программы чересчур тесно связаны.

Comment: @DreamChild, почему? Сплошь и рядом такое нужно для тестирования.

Answer (score 3):

Заверните ваши библиотечные классы в адаптер, и пусть адаптер реализует какой-либо интерфейс. При тестирование "подменяйте" уже интерфейс.

Например, хотите протестить библиотечный класс `FileLogger`

```
interface IFileLogger
{
    void Log(string log);
}

class FileLoggerAdapter : IFileLogger
{
    private FileLogger _fileLogger;

    public void Log(string log)
    {
       _fileLogger.Log(log);
    }  
}
```

Разумеется, адаптер стоит заводить только в том случае, если ваш библиотечный класс сам не реализует подходящего интерфейса.

В юнит-тесте потом просто подменяете реализацию `IFileLogger` на mock-объект

Comment: Согласен. Для создания mock-ов рекомендую [googlemock][1].


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/

Comment: Не понимаю как мне применить ваш подход, скажем, вот в такой ситуации.

Есть qt-шные библиотеки, которые я подключаю к своему тесту и мне необходимо, чтобы вместо класс QIODevice использовался класс написанный мной.

Comment: @lagartos, не используйте конкретные классы, используйте интерфейсы. Т. е. везде, где используется ваш конкретный `QIODevice` заменить на интерфейс. 

Этот вариант, как по мне, наиболее верный с точки зрения хорошей архитектуры. Правда, если при написании системы, её сделали зависимой от конкретных классов, то тут придётся изрядно поработать (да, нужно будет заменить всё, что хотите протестировать на интерфейсы).

Ну и возможно, что для с++, подмена lib и `#define` вполне себе годный вариант.